# Add custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver without having to declare mvc dependency

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-annotations

In my project I'm using the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation on a few methods of a `@RestController`. The only information I need tough, is the `id` field of the custom principal.

Currently this looks pretty ugly:

```
public void deleteUsers(@RequestParam(name = "id") List<Long> userIds, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
    if (userDetails != null && userIds.contains(((MyUser) userDetails).getId())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot delete self");
    }
    userManager.deleteUsers(userIds);
}
```

That's why I came up with the idea of a `@AuthenticationId` which gets resolved by a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

The thing is, that my project currently does not rely on the `spring-mvc` dependency. As I've seen, I would need to declare this dependency to register a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` myself: [Inject your custom method argument in Spring MVC using HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/06/spicy-spring-inject-custom-method-argument-spring-mvc/)

This seems a bit odd.

If the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` concept relies on `spring-mvc`, how can  `@AuthenticationPrincipal` work if I do not include the dependency?

Comment: How can you use `@RequestParam` if you don't use Spring MVC? Isn't `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` in the same JAR?

Comment: You are already using Spring MVC else the controller and handler methods wouldn't even work. So basically your logic/reasoning is flawed as you already have Spring MVC.

Comment: That's where the weird behaviour starts. Apparently the `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver` gets added over a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. So this must be included, otherwise I would not be able to use `@AuthenticationPrincipal`. Although when trying to implement a custom `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, the dependency cannot be found and I manually would need to ad the `spring-mvc` dependency first.